# Flutter url_launcher universal links in-app navigation

Tags: flutter, mobile, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open links from my flutter application.
I also have universal links. They are correctly configured as they start the application when I try to access a matching universal link.

However, I have an issue with in-app navigation. The issue does not happen on all the devices.
I try to navigate to an universal link using the `launch` method provided by `url_launcher`. As I'm already inside the application, it should be handled as an universal link and open the app or, at least on Android, ask with which application I want to open the link with.

As I said it depends on the device.

It works on:

- Poco X3 NFC (Android 11)

But it doesn't on:

- iPhone 12 Pro Max (iOS 14.5 & iOS 15+)
- Pixel 6 (Android 12)

I've seen [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25991) reported inside the flutter github repo but none of the solutions worked.

Did I missed something on the configuration? Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: I got the same on iOS only. Even though it worked well by clicking link from some another external apps (telegram/slack..), but it doesn't when clicking link from my in-app (my app is chat app) or Notes app for eg. Any solutions now?